# nodejs with mssql connection timeout error

Tags: sql-server, node.js, npm

I am writing a node.js console app for communicating with SQL Server 2008.

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var connection = new sql.Connection({
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
    database: 'Demo'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
     if (err) console.log(err);

    var request = new sql.Request(connection); // or: var request = connection1.request();
    request.query('select * from EmpInfo', function (err, recordset) {
        // ... error checks

        console.dir(recordset);
    })
});
```

When I execute this code, a `TIMEOUT` error occurs.

Answer (score 8):

１．you have to run "SQL Server Browser" service.

[image]

---

２．enable "TCP/IP"

[image]

*you need restart "SQLEXPRESS" service

---

it also helps bellow error.

```
ConnectionError: Port for SQLEXPRESS not found in "ServerName"
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your query takes too long.
Try to do `SELECT 1 a`.
If it works - change the timeout. 
Doc for [requestTimeout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql):

Answer (score 1):

Actually It was error from "Sql Server Configuration Manager". Tcp\Ip was disabled in Sql server network configuration.